# Difference between setImageResource() and setImageLevel()

Tags: android

Is there an advantage in using `setImageLevel()` with `LevelListDrawable`?
I looked it up but there were only small examples.

I usually use `setImageResource()` a lot of times and I'd like to know if is better with the other method.

Comment: It would depend on the use case. If you have different stages for the same image view then use setImageLevel otherwise just use setImageResource

Comment: find proper definitions and difference here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on use case. If you should show different images on `ImageView`, using `LeveListDrawable` would make your code more decoupled and cleaner.

Let's say in your `ImageView`, you should show different emotions like facebook has and you'd need to show user which reaction they have chosen.

[image: facebook emotions]

We could show proper emotion image every time using `if` or `switch` statement.

```
private void setProperImageForEmotion() {
    int emotion = 1; // Let's imagine 1 is for like, ... , 6 is for angry
    int resId = getCorrectDrawableSource(emotion);
}

private int getCorrectDrawableSource(int emotion) {
    switch (emotion) {
        case 2:
            return R.drawable.love;
        case 3:
            return R.drawable.haha;
        case 4:
            return R.drawable.wow;
        case 5:
            return R.drawable.sad;
        case 6:
            return R.drawable.angry;
        default:
            return R.drawable.like;
    }
}
```

Imagine that in future you have to add more emotions which makes you to add extra drawables to your `switch` statement. However, using `LevelListDrawable` will make your code much more cleaner and you do not have to add unrelated drawable ids to your Java or Kotlin code. Therefore, if we change above code to use `LevelListDrawable`, your code would look like this:

1. You need to create drawable file which will hold references to other drawable and you can define different levels:

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/like" />
  <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/love" />
  <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/haha" />
  <item android:maxLevel="4" android:drawable="@drawable/wow" />
  <item android:maxLevel="5" android:drawable="@drawable/sad" />
  <item android:maxLevel="6" android:drawable="@drawable/angry" />
 </level-list>
```

2. Now in your Java or Kotlin code, you can set proper level:

```
private void setProperImageForEmotion() {
    int emotion = 1; // Let's imagine 1 is for like, ... , 6 is for angry
    imageView.setImageLevel(emotion);
}
```

As you can see, it simplifies the code. Also, you can use `LevelListDrawable` for setting icon in [Notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int,%20int)) and [NotificationCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int,%20int)).